# javascript window.open() method still open in new tab while user hold the ctrl button

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

I am using the following code to open the question paper in popup window and it's working fine but when user hold the ctrl button and click on the start button it still open in new tab i am using the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#start').on('click', function(){
     
            window.open ('webURL',"mywindow", "width="+screen.availWidth+",height="+screen.availHeight, "status=1,toolbar=0");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Because you didn't check the CTRL there. Do you want the window to be not opened if CTRL is pressed?

Comment: yes but i don't know how to do this please can you show me how to do that. i am new here

Comment: And you have a typo: `window.open ('webURL',"mywindow", "width="+screen.availWidth+",height="+screen.availHeight+",status=1,toolbar=0");` or just

`window.open ('webURL',"mywindow", "status,width="+screen.availWidth+",height="+screen.availHeight);`

Comment: Interesting ,I didn't know Chrome had that feature ;-). You can currently workaround it by wrapping your call to open in a small timeout (e.g 10ms), but I'm not sure how long it will work, nor if all UAs will then accept the call at all.

Comment: it working with the timeout of 10ms. thanks to all for helping

Answer (score 0):

Check the `event` object's `ctrlKey` property.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#start').on('click', function(event){
            if(event.ctrlKey)
               window.open ('webURL',"mywindow", "width="+screen.availWidth+",height="+screen.availHeight+ ",status");
        });
    });
```

Comment: OP wants to ALSO pop if they hold ctrl